# Convert a generic collection to a List of strings

Tags: c#, .net, generics

After searching the board, i was not able to find a solution to my problem.

I have written the following code that works pretty well:

```
public static  void CreateFile(this List<string> lines,File_attribute fa)
{
     using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fa.OutpoutFolder+ fa.FileName ))
     {
         foreach (string line in lines)
         {

             file.WriteLine(line);

         }
     }
}
```

Now, i want to be able to do just this with a generic collection of object. I want each property to just be "ToStringed".  Here is the start of my code:

```
public static void CreateFile<T>(this List<T> lines, File_attribute fa)
{
    List<string> mylist = new List<string>();
    ...............
    ...............
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can define that T is of type object, just add where T : object. object has ToString

Comment: @anhoppe structs can be `ToString`'d as well

Comment: @anhoppe `T` is already object...

Comment: But then you should always be able to use ToString, shouldn't you?

Comment: @anhoppe That's it! `T` is implicitly `object` and structs are boxed as `object`.

Comment: Then Bertrand can do it almost like in the original string-only approach. Just foreach over the generic collection and call ToString on each element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible alternate approach using `string.Join`:

```
public static void CreateFile<T>(this List<T> lines, File_attribute fa)
{
     File.WriteAllText
     (
          Path.Combine(fa.OutpoutFolder, fa.FileName),
          string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines)
     );
}
```

So `string.Join` will internally call `Object.ToString()`!

Comment: Combining everything into a single string might not be the best approach depending on the size of the collection passed in. Maybe the OP was using a stream with an iteration over the collection for a reason, then again maybe not...

Comment: @Igor I've raised the same concern as a comment in your own answer... Imagine that OP has a `List<T>` of 100k items... wouldn't be this a bad practice *per se*?

Comment: @Igor **Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil.** http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization

Comment: @Igor You Arent Gonna Need It: **"Always implement things when you actually need them, never when you just foresee that you need them."** http://wiki.c2.com/?YouArentGonnaNeedIt

Comment: @Igor, I just want to export my collection as CSV and this is the way i think about doing it.

Comment: @BertrandPaul Just to clarify things... How many items may contain your lists?

Comment: Thanks all for the head up!

Comment: from a few dozens lines to thousands of objects.

Comment: @BertrandPaul So maybe my approach might have perf/memory issues with thousands of objects... BTW I would try to avoid having lists with thousands of objects, maybe you should work with chunks in your entire flow...

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ for this

```
public static void CreateFile<T>(this List<T> lines, File_attribute fa)
{
    List<string> mylist = lines.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList();
    ...............
    ...............
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `ToString` for every item, the rest can stay the same:

```
public static void CreateFile<T>(this List<T> items, File_attribute fa)
{
    using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fa.OutpoutFolder + fa.FileName))
    {
        foreach (T item in items)
            file.WriteLine(item.ToString());
    }
}
```

By doing it this way, for a huge list this will prevent your application from allocating a lot of memory before it can write anything to disk.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void CreateFile<T>(this List<T> lines)
{
    List<string> mylist = new List<string>();
    var props = typeof(T).GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
    foreach (var item in lines)
    {
        foreach (var prop in props)
        {
            var val = prop.GetValue(item);
            // do what you want with val, you can call ToString() on it
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that your answer is fine? :(

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer nope, but OP asks about ToStringing "each property" so maybe he wants to do that.

Comment: Meh I believe that OP wanted to say **items** instead of *properties*

Answer (score 0):

Although everything derives from `System.Object` and therefor implements `.ToString()` it is very easy to overlook this as a caller and use it on a type where you did not overwrite `.ToString()` which would then output the objects type instead of a some expected message. For better control I would highly recommend an interface and then use that as a generic constraint on your method.

```
public interface ILine {
    string GetLineOutput();
}
```

Then in your class.

```
public static  void CreateFile(this List<T> lines, File_attribute fa) where T : ILine
{
     using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(System.IO.Path.Combine(fa.OutpoutFolder, fa.FileName)))
     {
         foreach (ILine line in lines)
         {
             file.WriteLine(lin.GetLineOutput());
        }
     }
}
```

---

Some side notes

1. When creating a file path with variable parts you should use `System.IO.Path.Combine` to combine these parts.
2. Good job on using a stream and also writing to it line by line instead of all at once which *could* cause memory issues. Also good job on using `using` for your stream!

Comment: Isn't this over-engineering?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer - Not IMO. If you were to call this from various locations and never overwrite `ToString()` on the type passed in you would end up with output that contained nothing more than the qualified type name which is unexpected but would never raise any exceptions. The only way to catch it would be when you (some human) actually viewed the output.

Comment: And now I'll raise a good question for you: how do you implement `ILine` on a third-party library? :D

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer - no mention of any 3rd party libraries in the OP. I guess you could ask that on any answer that includes implementation on SO as I am sure 90% or more do not mention 3rd party libraries.

Comment: So why do you think Microsoft introduced extension methods instead of something like `ILinqEnumerators<T>` to be implemented in all collection types or even any `IEnumerable<T>`? They were implementing things on first-party libraries :D

Comment: In the other hand, about the thing of writing all lines at once, big collections (10k+) would be a memory leak before OP might hit memory issues when writing an entire list to disk. I assume that OP will try to write small lists to disk.........